# Code states that (x - 3) is not a function

Tags: javascript

Code states that (x-3) is not a function

```
</p>
<script>
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;

    if((x-3)(x-3) + (y+3)(y+3) === 16){
        document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "dab"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `if((x-3)*(x-3) + (y+3)*(y+3) === 16){}`

Comment: This is javascript code, not algebra.

Comment: By using the () operator after (x-3), you're asking the compiler to call (x-3) as if it were function. But (x-3) is not a function, it's a number.

Comment: In javascript (and most programming languages), multiplication needs to be explicit.

Comment: Why did I get 3 dislikes :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Javascript code, not *algebra* operations. Javascript `interpreter/compiler` sees `(x-3)(x-3)` as invoking of a function.

You have to use `*` operator for multiplication.

```js
var x = 1;
var y = 2;

if((x-3)*(x-3) + (y+3)*(y+3) === 29){
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "dab"
}
```

```html
<div id="id"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it took around 40 minutes after asking this to realize js thought that I was trying to run (x-3) as a function